# Unable to cancel editing in mobile web

Tags: bug, edits, mobile-web

While editing a post in mobile web I'm not seeing the Cancel button:

> [image: no cancel]

Full web has it:

> [image: full cancel]

Comment: @nicael so... should my question be tagged [tag:status-bydesign]?